# Looking for a very simple implementation of ckeditor and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have seen a few posts on how to create directives and controllers. However I am looking for something as simple as possible. Does anyone have any experience with creating some simple HTML code that allows me to use CKEditor. In particular the one thing I am not sure of is how to bind the editor contents to the model when I am using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link please check it

https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor

if you are interested in tinymce it is available in angularUI below is the link

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce